# fork in org-mode babel source block executes incorrectly

Tags: org-mode, c, programming

I have this small piece of code on emacs org-mode :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C :eval
#+BEGIN_SRC C :fork-example1.c :noweb no-export :eval :flags -Wall -Werror -pedantic
//Fork-exemplec-cours.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // pour fork
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Before fork, %d\n", i);
    fork();
    printf("After fork, %d\n", ++i);
    return 0;
}
#+END_SRC
```

And the result is the following:

```
#+RESULTS:
| Before fork | 0 |
| After fork  | 1 |
| Before fork | 0 |
| After fork  | 1 |
```

As you see there is an issue because I should have :

```
#+RESULTS:
| Before fork | 0 |
| After fork  | 1 |
| After fork  | 1 |
```

The most surprising is that I look for `/tmp/babel-5930pB/` and I execute 
`vince@debianvs:/tmp/babel-5930pB/$ ./C-bin-BbVB44`

I have exactly this :

```
Before fork, 0
After fork, 1
After fork, 1
```

Can you help me..... I can't understand why I have this behaviour in `org-mode`.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce it. Looks like a bug to me. Consider reporting it to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).